# Обновление веб-запроса на новый

Tags: c#, http, rest, c#-8.0

Есть запрос

```
var stroka = @"{""Items"":[{""Data"": null,""DataArray"":[],""Name"":""SessionToken"",""Value"":" + sessionToken + @"},{""Data"": null,""DataArray"":[],""Name"":""AuthToken"",""Value"":" + authToken + @"},{""Data"": null,""DataArray"":[],""Name"":""AuthorizationUser"",""Value"":" + value + @"}],""Value"":null}";


                    HttpWebRequest Updat = WebRequest.Create(String.Format($"http://127.0.0.1:8/API/REST/Entity/Update/{typeUid}/{ENTITYID}")) as HttpWebRequest;

                    Updat.Method = "POST";
                    Updat.Headers.Add("AuthToken", authToken);
                    Updat.Headers.Add("SessionToken", sessionToken);
                    Updat.Timeout = 100000;
                    Updat.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";

                 

                    var sentData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stroka);
                    Updat.ContentLength = sentData.Length;
                    Stream sendStream = Updat.GetRequestStream();
                    sendStream.Write(sentData, 0, sentData.Length);


                    var res3 = Updat.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
                    var resStream3 = res3.GetResponseStream();
                    var sr3 = new StreamReader(resStream3, Encoding.UTF8);
```

Но это, как мне сказали , старый вариант использования, как можно его переделать на новый?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не вдаваясь в подробности, получится как-то так

```
private static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    var stroka = @"{""Items"":[{""Data"": null,""DataArray"":[],""Name"":""SessionToken"",""Value"":" + sessionToken + @"},{""Data"": null,""DataArray"":[],""Name"":""AuthToken"",""Value"":" + authToken + @"},{""Data"": null,""DataArray"":[],""Name"":""AuthorizationUser"",""Value"":" + value + @"}],""Value"":null}";

    using HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, $"http://127.0.0.1:8/API/REST/Entity/Update/{typeUid}/{ENTITYID}");
    request.Content = new StringContent(stroka, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    request.Headers.Add("AuthToken", authToken);
    request.Headers.Add("SessionToken", sessionToken);
    using HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode(); // выброс исключения, если сервер ответил ошибкой
    string responseText = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

Хотя я настоятельно вам советовал бы научиться использовать [сериализацию JSON](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-overview).

Comment: Спасибо, а где передавать заголовки ?

Comment: @Teslaaaaa1 забыл про заголовки, переписал ответ

Comment: @Teslaaaaa1 только зачем вам здесь заголовки, если эти же самые данные есть в теле JSON запроса? Дублирования данных не должно быть.

Comment: В теле передаются данные, для заполнения справочника. Спасибо еще раз, очень выручили)